# Why is there a space behind a character created by the \symbol command?

Tags: formatting, symbols, unicode, white-space

I defined the following simple macro:

```
\def\greek#1{
\symbol{\numexpr"03B0+#1}
}
```

This is supposed to convert numbers into greek characters for numbering purposes (so 1 becomes α, 2 becomes β etc.). It does its job, but for some weird reason, it always creates a whitespace of about 3pt behind the character, so that `\greek{1}\greek{2}\greek{3}` looks like this:

[image]

when it should actually look like this:

[image]

I know that I can get rid of that space by simply doing something like

```
\def\greek#1{
\symbol{\numexpr"03B0+#1}\hspace{-3.33pt}
}
```

but that seems to be a rather "hacked" solution. Is there any better way to do this? Why does it even do that anyway?

Comment: `\def\greek#1{SPACE`  is a space (newlines are spaces in TeX (as they are in markdown or html on this site) You are adding two such spaces

Comment: `\def\greek#1{\symbol{\numexpr"03B0+#1}}` (although better to use `\newcommand` rather than `\def`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David has explained in comments; TeX adds spaces at the end of lines. Hence your code was having `SPACE<definition>SPACE`. Many programmers prefer to code on multiple lines like in your example. To achieve that and still not have unwanted spaces; you can use the comment character of TeX at the end of lines in definition like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\greek}[1]{% Space ignored.
  \symbol{\numexpr"03B0+#1}% Space ignored.
}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NewCM10-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\greek{1}\greek{2}\greek{3}
\end{document}
```

You will find this style of coding very commonly in the TeX-world.

You would need to use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX as this is Unicode.

##### Edit:

I have added the `\numexpr` part of the original answer back to my code after Enrico's remark in the comments. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: This only works if `#1` is a single hexadecimal digit, which is probably not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @egreg thanks. I will change the answer, but I was just wondering how `\numexpr"03B0+10` becomes `03BA`. What is the underlying magic that changes the `B` to `C`?

Comment: The argument to `\symbol` should be an integer; how it’s represented is irrelevant and `\numexpr` knows how to add numbers in different bases (decimal, octal, hexadecimal). `”03B0` is 944 and `\symbol{“03BA}` or `\symbol{954}` is the same.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the explanation. I will remember this.